# Behavior of $ f_p$ under generator $S\tau = ( -1 / \tau )$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I am self studying Tom M Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I could not think about a step in the proof of the theorem 4.6 in Chapter 4 which is

> If $f$ is automorphic under $\Gamma $ and if $p$ is a prime then, 
>   $$f_p( \frac {-1 } {\tau } )= f_p(\tau ) + \frac1p f(p \tau  ) -                \frac1p  f( \frac { \tau  } {p}  ).$$

For this a lemma is proved whose proof I completely understand but I am stating it

**Lemma**–  Let $ T_{\lambda }\tau  =  \dfrac {\lambda+ \tau  } {p}  $. Then for each $\lambda $ in interval $[1, p-1]$ , where $\lambda $ is always an integer, there exists an integer $\mu $ in same interval and a transformation $V$ in  $\Gamma_0 (p)$ such that $T_\lambda  S = V T_\mu $ . 
Moreover, as $\lambda$ runs through integers $1,2,\ldots,p-1$ so does $\mu$ .

What doubt I have is mentioned at the end of the post. But I am giving whole proof here for the sake of completion.

**Proof of theorem** – $$
\begin{aligned}
pf_p(\frac {-1} {\tau } ) &= \sum_{\lambda  =0 }^{p-1}  f(\frac {S\tau + \lambda } { p }    )\\
& = f(\frac {S\tau } {p}) + \sum_{\lambda=1}^{p-1}  f(T_\lambda S\tau )\\ 
&= f(\frac {-1} {\tau p}) + \ldots\\
&+ \text{( terms involving summation wrt $\lambda $ which are converted into summation}\\
&\text{$\sum_{\mu=0}^{p-1}$ by adding and subtracting $f(\frac {\tau  } {p}) $}\\ 
&= f(\tau p) + pf_p(\tau) - f(\frac { \tau} {p}  ) . 
\end{aligned}
$$
**My doubt** $\to$

> how $f(\frac {-1}  {\tau p} )$  in step 2 is written as $f(\tau p)$ in step 3.

Can anybody please give some hint.

Comment: @Jyrki Lathonen thank you very much. Can you please tell how you highlighted my doubt with yellow colour?

Comment: That is produced by the `>` at the beginning of the line. It is a property of the MarkUp language used here. Click the `Edit` -button below your question to see what the source looks like right now.

Comment: My copy of Apostol is in my office, and I am anything but familiar with this part of math. But won't the assumption that $f$ is automorphic allow you to apply $S$ to the variable, and possibly clear your doubt?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen no I think that argument incorrect  as there is 1/p in denominator which is going in numerator. So, I don't think your argument is valid.

Comment: I got to check out my copy of Apostol. I still think that $f(z)$ being automorphic means that $f(z)=f(Sz)=f(-1/z)$ for all $z\in H$. Applying this to $z=p\tau$ gives $f(p\tau)=f(-\dfrac1{p\tau})$, no?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen , yes you are right. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Let $$A_p = \{ M\in M_2(\Bbb{Z}),\  \det(M)\ = p\}$$ quotient $A_p$ on the left by  $\Gamma=SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ to obtain the disjoint union $$A_p = \bigcup_{j=1}^J \Gamma g_j$$

Let $S=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0}$ or any other element of $\Gamma$ then $$A_p= A_p S= \bigcup_{j=1}^J \Gamma g_j S$$
Since the left cosets are unique it means for some permutation
$$\Gamma g_j S=\Gamma g_{\sigma(j)}$$

For  $f\in M_k(SL_2(\Bbb{Z}))$ define the $p$-th weight $k$ Hecke operator for $\Gamma$
$$T_p f = \sum_{j=1}^J f|_k \Gamma g_j$$
We find
$$T_p f|_k S =\sum_{j=1}^J f|_k \Gamma g_j S=\sum_{j=1}^J f|_k \Gamma g_{\sigma(j)} = T_p f $$

You get your result by setting $f_p = p^{-k}(T_p f -f|_k \pmatrix{p & 0 \\ 0 & 1})$

When $f\in M_k(\Gamma)$ for a congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ we change  $A_p$ to $A_p=\Gamma \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\0 & p}\Gamma$ since we don't have $A_p S=A_p$ we don't have $T_p f= T_pf|_k S$ anymore.

Comment: . Can you please take a look at this question if you have some spare time for that. It's a important theorem in Ch - 2 of Apostol and I am badly struck on it. Please give some hints. Link is - 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465251/doubt-in-proof-of-a-theorem-in-tom-apostol-s-modular-functions-and-dirichlet-se

Comment: before writing line     -- We find $T_p f|_$ $

Comment: ... Continued from above  ,  before writing line     -- We find $T_p $ $ f|_k $  S ... , in the previous line you have written $ Tp $ f. So how $T_p$ f changes to $T_p$ $ f|_k $ S by introducing S both on LHS and RHS in step before in $T_p $ . Can you please explain?